# pass databinding itself as a parameter to be used outside its main class

Tags: android, android-databinding

is this code possible or any alternatives?

on xml you have like this,

```
 <Button....
      onClick="@{() -> adapter.itemClick(message, [here, pass binding resource like @this or context])}"
 >

 <TextView...
      id="@+id/tvName"
 >
```

then in your adapter class, you have

```
 fun itemClick(message: String, view: View) {
 view.tvName.text = "some text"
 }
```

I'm not sure if this is possible since it is my first time using databinding.

Comment: I think that if you can describe your goal, it would be easier for us to help you by suggesting common practice for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Anything that can be passed by a valid reference is possible. The question here: Do you have a valid reference to your binding class where you want to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @Kozmotronik, the reference I want to pass is the XML itself. since the XML is databinded, I need to pass it so I can use other view from that XML.

Comment: You can refer to other views directly within the xml. But as far as I know you can't refer to the binding class from within its xml. If you don't mind to share your implementation as a whole, I can suggest you some logic that will do the same job.